# Puppet - Parameter 'ensure' is already set on host_present[test] - cannot redefine

Tags: puppet, puppet-enterprise

I am trying to call the same method "host_present" twice. But I am facing the following error

Parameter 'ensure' is already set on host_present[test] by # at /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/modules/manifests/host_1.pp:12; cannot redefine at /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/modules/manifests/host_1.pp:13 on node devopenstack

```
define host_present()
{
        host { 'puppet_host':
        persona    => 'TEST',
        url        => 'https://user:password',
        }
}

host_present{"test": ensure => present}
host_present["test"]{ ensure => absent}
```

Can someone help.

Answer (score 0):

Those are not methods, they are resources. Puppet is a declarative language. When you declare on one line `ensure => present` and then on the next `ensure => absent`, Puppet understands this as two inconsistent declarations about the end-state, and so it throws an error.

You will need to spend some time learning Puppet from tutorials, etc.